# Jersey GAE Reflection Exception

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jersey-2.0

I'm developing a RESTful web service using Jersey and Google App Engine. Locally it's running fine, but when I deploy it to Google App Engine and try to do a GET on a url I get:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Reflection is not allowed on private final int java.lang.String.count
at com.google.appengine.runtime.Request.process-065e70ad10135af7(Request.java)
at org.glassfish.jersey.linking.FieldDescriptor$1.run(FieldDescriptor.java:88)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:34)
at org.glassfish.jersey.linking.FieldDescriptor.setAccessibleField(FieldDescriptor.java:85)
at org.glassfish.jersey.linking.FieldDescriptor.getFieldValue(FieldDescriptor.java:65)
at org.glassfish.jersey.linking.FieldProcessor.processLinks(FieldProcessor.java:151)
at org.glassfish.jersey.linking.FieldProcessor.processLinks(FieldProcessor.java:82)
at org.glassfish.jersey.linking.LinkFilter.filter(LinkFilter.java:86)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerFilteringStage$ResponseFilterStage.apply(ContainerFilteringStage.java:238)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ContainerFilteringStage$ResponseFilterStage.apply(ContainerFilteringStage.java:202)
at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.Stages.process(Stages.java:171)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.processResponse(ServerRuntime.java:376)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.process(ServerRuntime.java:368)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:262)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:320)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:236)
at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1028)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:373)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:381)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:344)
at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:219)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
at com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter.doFilter(CORSFilter.java:169)
at com.thetransactioncompany.cors.CORSFilter.doFilter(CORSFilter.java:232)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.googlecode.objectify.cache.AsyncCacheFilter.doFilter(AsyncCacheFilter.java:58)
at com.googlecode.objectify.ObjectifyFilter.doFilter(ObjectifyFilter.java:48)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:437)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:444)
at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:188)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:308)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:300)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:441)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: Reflection is not allowed on private final int java.lang.String.count
    ... 54 more

I read that it maybe related to Reflection that is not allowed on GAE. Is there a way to disable Reflection in jersey?

Answer (score 0):

I solved that updating from 2.7 to 2.8